# Is there an auto-close curly brackets plugin for the Geany IDE?

Tags: geany, curly-brackets, auto-close

Geany is the closest thing I can find to the perfect web development IDE. However, I can't find a way to automatically close curly brackets *(`{`)*.

For example, typing:

```
function test()
{
```

..and pressing <kbd>RETURN</kbd> should cause this to happen:

```
function test()
{
    // cursor ends up here (indented by 1 tab)
}
```

Is there anything that can make Geany do that?

Answer (score 5):

This is a native feature of Geany,

Go to Preferences, then Completions, down there you can choose which one you want to auto close.

[Check here for screenshots](http://www.geany.org/manual/current/#editor-completions-preferences)

Comment: I was already aware of that. However, it doesn't work on the Windows platform. Believe me I've tried.

Comment: Then have you submitted the bug? Submit the bug, likely if they don't offer a patch they will at least give you a workaround, sorry I didn't help.

Comment: This has been known and unfixed for a very long time. The only workaround is for someone to make a plugin which is the reason I made this post.

Comment: This way I get `{\n\t%cursor%}`. I want get `{\n\t%cursor%\n}`, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You make something else:
If you want, open https://plugins.geany.org/autoclose.html and see "autoclose" plugin. You can install with :
sudo apt-get install geany-plugins-autoclose
and It is all

Answer (score 0):

That isn't full answer to your question, but may be helpful.

*I have Geany not in english, I make translations of menu's fields on my own.*

Geany has a feature: when you type special text and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, the text is going to be replaced with another text.

It works by default for `if`, `else`, `for`, `while`, `do`, `switch` and `try`.

Configuration of this feature is in `[Tools]/[Config files]/[snippets.conf]`.
After doing some changes, save file and click `[Tools]/[Reload configuration]`.

I added two lines to section C++:

```
class=class %cursor%%block%;\n
struct=struct %cursor%%block%;\n
```

With `block=\s{\n\t%cursor%\n}`

It doesn't let you press <kbd>{</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>{</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd> to get

```
{
    //cursor
}
```

because `{=anything` is ignored, I don't know why.

What you can do? You can have some another text, replaced using `{\n\t%cursor%\n}`, or define keybinding inserting it.

Answer (score 0):

Geany can have user defined snippets. It is possible to open snippet configuration file from menu.

```
Tools ->
        Configuration files ->
                               snippets.conf
```

Go to the language block where you want to add that feature.
For example:

```
  [C]
  if=if (%cursor%)%block_cursor%
  else=else%block_cursor%
  for=for (i = 0; i < %cursor%; i++)%block_cursor%
  while=while (%cursor%)%block_cursor%
  do=do\n{\n\t%cursor%\n} while (%cursor%)\n%cursor%
  switch=switch (%cursor%)%brace_open%case %cursor%:\n\t\t%cursor%\n\t\tbreak;\n\tdefault:\n\t\t%cursor%\n%brace_close%%cursor%
```

At first it can be thought that the problem can be fixed just with adding this line

```
 {=%\n{\n\t%cursor%\n}%
```

But Geany does not accept that when snippet is one non alphabetic character.
It will work for any other alphabetic character like this

```
 b=%\n{\n\t%cursor%\n}% or  bl=%\n{\n\t%cursor%\n}%
```

However I dont think it is what you want. The real solution you can find from geanys menu.

```
 Edit
      ->Preferences
                    ->Editor
                            ->Completions
```

Tick the Auto-close quotes and brackets then click on apply and save[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Auto-close doesn't work if we place brackets inside another pair of brackets. For example, the inner bracket doesn't auto-close.`{{|}`

However, we can use the following snippet to create a block.

```
{={\n\t%cursor%\n}
```

But in order to use this snippet, we first have to include '**{**' char in our **wordchars** set by changing the below line in snippets.conf file.

```
wordchars=_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789{
```